# Unable to save the last xml file php

Tags: php, xml

I am fairly new to php, and I have written code to work with the amazon API. When I request information from the API, I receive it, but am unable to sort through the XML. Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on null in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\Phillip\src\MarketplaceWebServiceProducts\Samples\csv_prep.php on line 117
```

Here is the code:

```
if(is_array($xmlFiles)){
    foreach($xmlFiles as $xmlFile){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
        foreach($xml->GetMatchingProductForIdResult as $items) {        
             //Line 117 ->
           if(isset($items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount) !== False) { 
                $amount = $items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount
            }else{
                $amount = '0.00';
            }
       }
   }
 }
```

The tag in the XML that I am trying to get the value of looks like this:

```
<ns2:amount>9.99</ns2:amount>
```

It is in the same place as it says in the code. I only have this problem with large files and I am not sure what is happening. If someone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be very, very helpful if you could post the relevant part of XML. Also, is that all of the error output?

Comment: It is posted. At least the path is. I found the problem. The error is within the $items tag. It goes `Id, type, status` the status isn't success. It is client error. How would I check for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but based on the error message, it looks like somewhere in the `$items->Products->Product->AttributeSets` hierarchy something you're specifying does not exist.

Do tests to see if `$items` or `$items->Products` or `$items->Products->Product` or `$items->Products->Product->AttributeSets` and whichever one fails, print out that fact and call `exit;`.

You could do a `print_r` on `$items` to help as well.

Comment: You were right, there was a problem with the high arcky. The status was `client error` instead of `success`. In the `GetMatchingProductForId` tag in the xml there is a the status with in the tag. How would I go about getting the text that is in the status area of the tag?

Comment: @Robert Great to hear.  You should mark this answer as accepted and then ask that question as a new question since it's something different.  Thx

Comment: How would I go about checking the high arcky? see my other post here: [My Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828958/getting-item-inside-an-xml-tag-and-call-to-children-on-null-error)